# JQuery (mobile) bind touchstart wont work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, panel

im using jquery mobile for an web application. Now, you know ;-), jquery mobile is pretty slow using normal tap events.

I've found some various solutions to speed up the navigation one of this is following:

instead of using `<a href="#ID" data-role....>...</a>` im using : `<a id="ID_btn">...</a>` and then :

```
$('#ID_btn').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    if(event.handled !== true) {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#ID",{ transition: "slide"});
                        event.handled = true;
                    }
                });
```

This works pretty fine and speed the app up from maybe 1sec delay to maybe 100-200ms.

But there is one tricky button that wont work a shown above. This is the button for showing my root panel:

So i have :

```
<body> 
        <div data-role="page" id="news" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <div data-role="panel" id="menue" data-position="left" data-theme="b" >
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="header" id="news_header">
                <h1>News</h1>
                <a id="#menue_btn" data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-left">Menue</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" id="news_content"> 
                <ul data-role="listview" id="news_content_list" data-inset="true">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and so on and a JS snippet :

```
function init(){

        menue = $('#menue');
        menueBtn = $('#menue_btn');
        menueBtn.bind('touchstart', function(e) {
            event.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            if(event.handled !== true) {
                //alert(1);
                menue.panel("open", {display: 'push', position: 'left'});
                event.handled = true;
            }
        });
    }
$( document ).ready(function() {
        init();
});
```

I can't ven get the alert() so i think I've done something wrong with the binding.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think `event.preventDefault()` should be `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: yeah, sure , my bad ;-) but seems to change nothing ^^ the button wont work

Comment: Your button id has the hash character in it(id="#menue_btn"). It probably should be id="menue_btn"